# canvas.drawBitmap draws only last modified bitmap, not intermediates

Tags: java, android, canvas, view

In my personal Input Method, Im using a small mutable bitmap for temporary draw (with a canvas), then I draw this bitmap into a bigger one. This work well on SurfaceView using a separate thread for drawing. I currently reworking the code to do the draw on the UI thread, using View instead of SurfaceView because of reasons. The problem is when I draw into the small bitmap using the canvas, and then draw the small bitmap into the bigger one, and making this process multiples times, is like the bitmapcall is drawing only the last modification of the small bitmap.

Here is a short piece of code that I made for show to you

```
public class TestBMP extends View {

    private Bitmap bmp;
    private Canvas bmpCanvas;
    private Paint paint;

    public TestBMP(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TestBMP(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TestBMP(Context context,  AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(128,128, conf);
        bmpCanvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (canvas.getHeight() == 0)
            return;

        int max = 3;
        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            bmpCanvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
            bmpCanvas.drawText("T:"+i, 64, 64, paint );
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, i*(canvas.getWidth() / max), canvas.getHeight() / 2, null);
        }

    }
}
```

If you execute this in a Activity (or in custom input method), there are 3 red squares, with the text "T:2" and not the expected result with (T:0 --- T:1 --- T:2). Thanks.

EDIT:
If i use a big bitmap as buffer with size of canvas and draw the smalls bitmaps into this buffer and at the end, draw the buffer into view's canvas, works as expected. What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I answer my question. It seems that is related to hardware acceleration. I can disable it in a view level using

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

And all works as expected. I guess the drawing is more slower in that way, but works for me.

My guess is that the multiples drawBitmap is caching on the canvas with the reference to the bitmap, so, if I change the bitmap, the draw calls point to the same modified bitmap. And the ends of onDraw method, the same bitmap in the last modifications draws instead of the secuential changes.